# Bringing activity on top while screen locked

Tags: java, android, qt, qml

I'm developing a `VOIP` application with `Qt/QML` in Android, other `VOIP` applications like WhatsApp and Skype, bring up their call activities when the incoming call is received and screen is locked. I am trying to implement something like this.

I have two questions:

1. What about implementing this feature completely in Java
2. Implementing this feature with QML and bringing qml activity on top when the screen is locked

I have implemented a simple java call screen with window manager and  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`, but i think its very platform specific and may not work in different API versions

In second case, i want to draw call screen into QML activity and show that on locked screen, but i don't know how to do it.

Could someone tell what is the correct approach for this feature and if the second one is correct, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If the user doesnt have high security lock i mean (Just Swipe/ none) then you can use the below code

```
private void turnScreenOn() {
    int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON;
    getWindow().addFlags(flags);
}
```

Use the above code in OnCreate of your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    turnScreenOn();
    setContentView(R.layout.alexa_alarm_actvity);

}
```

Remember before setContentView

Also add the permission in manifest.

android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD

Best Regds

Comment: As you said, this is working just in case simple security lock.